# Rendering another layout inside index.php

Tags: php

I am following this [Link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/organize-your-next-php-project-the-right-way--net-5873) to understand the basic framework of PHP Web app but I am not able to understand how can I switch back and forth to the different layouts (Articles, Portfolio) through navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

All different layout must be like index.php.

Image you have articles.php and portfolio.php. There content would be like:

Articles.php:

```
<?php    
// load up your config file
require_once("/path/to/resources/config.php");

require_once(TEMPLATES_PATH . "/header.php");
?>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <!-- Your article content here!!! -->
</div>
<?php
    require_once(TEMPLATES_PATH . "/rightPanel.php");
?>
</div>
<?php
    require_once(TEMPLATES_PATH . "/footer.php");
?>
```

and portfolio.php:

```
<?php    
// load up your config file
require_once("/path/to/resources/config.php");

require_once(TEMPLATES_PATH . "/header.php");
?>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <!-- Your portfolio content here!!! -->
</div>
<?php
    require_once(TEMPLATES_PATH . "/rightPanel.php");
?>
</div>
<?php
    require_once(TEMPLATES_PATH . "/footer.php");
?>
```

But everytime you add a new page, you must update your header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Simple Site</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Simple Site</h1>
    <ul class="nav global">
        <li><a href="path_to_index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="path_to_article.php">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="path_to_portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="path_to_any_other_page.php">Any other page</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't we just call the index.php on every navigation click and pass any variable from them (from article, portfolio.php)  to the index, so that it could render the layout according to the variable it receives?

Comment: using php, you could. You change your link this way: 
<li><a href="path_to_index.php?page=article">Article</a></li>
and in your index page:
<div id="content">
if(//page = article){//article content}else {//index content}
  
</div>

Answer (score 0):

This is what actually I wanted to achieve

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=calculator">Calculator</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=About">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I am sending the page variable to the index and then it is rendering the layout accordingly through this way.

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])){
    $page=$_GET["page"];
}
else { 
    $page = "home";
}

renderLayoutWithContentFile($page .".php", $variables);
```